# Помогите с оформлением по MVC кода на джаве

Tags: java, mvc

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
    }
}

class Controller {
    public int age = 20;
    public String name = "Sasha";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    Controller() {
        Model model = new Model();
    }
}


class Model {
    Model() {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        String name = controller.getName();
        int age = controller.getAge();
        View view = new View();
        view.showStudent(name, age);
    }
}


class View {
    public void showStudent(String name, int age) {
        System.out.println("name  " + name + "age  " + age);
    }
}
```

Не могу разобраться с mvc. Помогите пожалуста. Надо чтобы контроллер видел только модель. В контроллер просто вносятся данные, которые затем выводятся во вью.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не совсем правильно поняли принцип MVC, в вашей реализации данные хранятся в контроллере, а модель владеет и управляет контроллером и view.

Данные необходимо хранить в моделе, view должно иметь возможность взаимодействовать с интерфейсом, а контроллер должен управлять моделью и view.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
    }
}

class Controller {
    Model model = new Model();
    View view = new View();

    Controller() {
        view.showStudent(model.getName(), model.getAge());
    }
}


class Model {
    public int age = 20;
    public String name = "Sasha";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}


class View {
    public void showStudent(String name, int age) {
        System.out.println("name  " + name + "age  " + age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Только модель и вью не создаются в контроллере. Они инжектятся туда. Весь прикол єтого шаблона состоит в том, чтобы подставлять контроллеру разные модели и вьюхи, а он это все обрабатывал

Comment: Да, только в этом коде это ещё бы сложнее было показать